# Creating Calendars on my Mac

Tags: icloud, ical

I would like to be able to take my iCal off iCloud entirely. I've attempted to disable it using both iCloud preferences and iCal account settings- and both times the calendars disappeared. However, that means that every time I attempt to create a new calendar, there is no option for where to do it. Without the File>New Calendar>iCloud option, they simply don't exist. Shouldn't there be a File>New Calendar>On My Mac option? Is it possible that I deleted my "On My Mac" folder?

Thanks!
Unsure

Comment: Are you trying to create a new calendar or keep your iCloud calendars after iCloud is turned off?

Comment: What OS do you have?